# Find the green area

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, problem-solving, area

**How to find the green area**
[image]

### My attempt

Each area is $\pi r_n^2=\dfrac{4\pi}{\left(n^2+2\right)^2}$. We can approximate $\sum_1^\infty \dfrac{4\pi}{\left(n^2+2\right)^2}$ to be $\int_1^\infty \dfrac{4\pi}{\left(n^2+2\right)^2}dn$. Let us evaluate the indefinite integral $\int\dfrac{4\pi}{\left(n^2+2\right)^2}=4\pi\int\dfrac1{\left(n^2+2\right)^2}dn$ first.

We use a trig sub - let $n=\sqrt2\tan\theta\implies dn=\sqrt2\sec^2\theta~d\theta$. We end up with:
\begin{align*}
\int\dfrac1{\left(2\tan^2\theta+2\right)^2}~dn&=\int\dfrac1{4\left(\sec^2\theta\right)^2}~dn \\
&=\dfrac14\int\dfrac1{\sec^4\theta}\sqrt2\sec^2\theta~d\theta \\
&=\dfrac1{2\sqrt2}\int\dfrac1{\sec^2\theta}~d\theta \\
&=\dfrac1{2\sqrt2}\int\cos^2\theta~d\theta \\
&=\dfrac1{4\sqrt2}\int1+\cos(2\theta)~d\theta \\
&=\dfrac1{4\sqrt2}\left(\theta+\dfrac{\sin(2\theta)}2\right) \\
&=\dfrac1{8\sqrt2}(2\theta+\sin(2\theta)) \\
\theta&=\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac n{\sqrt2}\right) \\
I&=\dfrac1{8\sqrt2}\left(2\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac n{\sqrt2}\right)+\sin\left(2\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac n{\sqrt2}\right)\right)\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: Why downvote ??

Comment: i didnt downvote, but what is the question?

Comment: also there is no motivation or source given

Comment: @jimjim I'm new here, so maybe I don't know some things, but I've observed many questions without attempts, sources, or motivation still receiving answers. When someone asks about the motivation, there's no reply, yet these questions still get many upvotes. Not complaining, just an observation.

Comment: Haha , wait a while , you'll see correct answers that get downvoted or even deleted by force , good questions that get downvoted but when someone else asks the same question gets upvoted. What i said above is just general rules , but still even you do the right thing you can still punished. I stopped caring about up or down , right or or wrong , less stress.

Comment: Almost the same issue [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/903834/305862) with interesting methods.

Answer (score 3):

This is a special case of the Pappus chain, your equation for the area of the nth circle in the chain is correct, however this is not an integration problem but a summation one. The area is simply $\pi+8\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over(n^2+2)^2}\approx6.99796$

Comment: You may upload it here https://discord.com/channels/624314920158232616/862715432527593532